# Delete all href attribute in Wordpress posts

Tags: links

i want to replace all links with plain text. So

```
<a href="http://www.anydomain.com/2">anchor text</a>
```

should be just

```
anchor text
```

So I tried regex and it works here https://regex101.com/r/4q4nPf/1
but not in the plugin i used
I tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

[Screenshot of Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5Tp.png)

any idea how i can do this?

Update:
just use

```
/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/
```

Comment: Did you try adding a delimiter around your regex pattern? That's what the little note on the bottom of your screenshot says. So for instance, /<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/ , noting the added slashes. (Since this is replacing stuff in your database, let me say, use at your own risk.)

Answer (score 1):

Moving comment to answer:

Did you try adding a delimiter around your regex pattern? That's what the little note on the bottom of your screenshot says. So for instance, /]*>(.*?)</a>/ , noting the added slashes. (Since this is replacing stuff in your database, let me say, use at your own risk.)